# Winkeltreu nur in Kartographie?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, mathematics

Ist der Begriff "winkeltreu" nur in der Kartographie gebräuchlich, oder kann ich ihn auch in der folgenden Situation benutzen?

Es gibt Geometrieaufgaben bei denen man Winkel aus den gegebenen Längen mit Hilfe von Winkelsätzen, Trigonometrie, usw. **berechnen** soll.

Um zu vermeiden, dass die Schüler/Studenten, die Winkel *ausmessen*, werden die gegebenen Figuren häufig so gezeichnet, dass die Längen/Winkel nicht mit den angegebenen übereinstimmen.

Für einen Hinweis hierauf, wäre:

> Achtung: Zeichnung ist nicht winkeltreu!

möglich, oder gibt es ein geeigneteres Wort als "winkeltreu" in diesem Zusammenhang?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Winkeltreue* ist in der Geometrie und Kartografie die

> genaue Übereinstimmung von Winkeln geometrischer Figuren und Abbildungen

(Duden). Damit ist i.A. nicht eine zahlenmäßige Übereinstimmung, sondern eine geometrische Übereinstimmung gemeint. *Winkeltreu* kann also nur eine Figur zu einer anderen sein.

Lautet deine Aufgabe z.B.

> zeichne die abgebildete Figur im Maßstab 1:2

und die Winkel der Lösung sind nicht gleich wie in der ursprünglichen Zeichnung, dann kannst du sehr wohl sagen, dass die Figuren nicht winkeltreu sind, wenn deine Aufgabe aber lautet

> zeichne ein Dreick mit den Winkeln 80°, 40° und 60°

und die Winkel in der Lösung sind 45°, 85° und 50°, dann kann man wohl nicht von *winkeltreu* reden, da es keine Vergleichsfigur gibt. Hier sind die Winkel ganz einfach *falsch*.

Geht es darum, dass eine Abbildung nur eine Beispielabbildung ist und die angegebenen Winkel nicht mit denen in der Beispielzeichnung übereinstimmen, dann habe ich schon

> winkelgetreu

vergleichbar mit

> maßstabsgetreu

gelesen und würde das auch so verwenden. Duden meint allerdings, *winkeltreu* und *winkelgetreu* seien Synonyme. Ich sehe hier (genau bei deinem Beispiel) einen kleinen Unterschied.

Comment: Ich dachte dabei eher an Aufgaben, bei denen eine Zeichnung gegeben ist. Zum Beispiel: Ein Dreieck ist gezeichnet mit zwei gegebenen WInkeln von (in Text) 30 und 60 Grad die jedoch in der Zeichnung (gemessen) 28 und 55 Grad groß sind.

Comment: Das wäre ja dann der zweite Teil der Antwort - dort bin ich genau darauf eingegangen.

Comment: Der Ausdruck _...nicht eine zahlenmäßige Übereinstimmung..._ macht keinen Sinn, da die Größe der Winkel durch Zahlen angegeben werden.

Comment: @tofro "zeichne ein Dreieck mit den Winkeln 90°, 40° und 60°" - um ein Dreieck mit Winkelsumme 190° hinzukriegen, musst Du aber schon in die sphärische Trigonometrie gehen :-P [/Klugscheißermodus]

Comment: @VolkerLandgraf Das ist hier *German Language*. Über die Winkelsumme im Dreick denke ich (manchmal) auf *Mathematics* nach ;)

Answer (score 5):

Winkeltreue ist eine Eigenschaft von Abbildungen, insbesondere der Projektionen aus der Kartografie, die Du erwähnst. Deine Zeichnung bildet auch die Realität ab, aber ist nicht in allen Aspekten treu, eben nicht für Winkel. Ich sehe kein Problem mit Deiner Verwendung des Begriffs.

Answer (score 1):

Neben »winkeltreu« (was möglich wäre) könntest du auch mit dem angehängten Adjektiv »konform« arbeiten.

> Achtung: Zeichnung ist nicht winkelkonform!

Dazu der [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/_konform):

> *-konform:* drückt in Bildungen mit Substantiven aus, dass die beschriebene Sache mit etwas übereinstimmt

Im Übrigen heißt in der Mathematik eine »winkeltreue Abbildung« auch »[konforme Abbildung](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Konforme_Abbildung)«; mit »konform« ist hier also »winkelkonform« gemeint.

Comment: Ja gut, aber man kann sich natürlich alle möglichen Wörter ausdenken; winkelgenau, winkelgerecht, winkelrecht, richtigwinklig, winkelexakt, winkelgleich...

Comment: Ich denke, _winkelkonform_ ist eine semantisch unmögliche Zusammensetzung. _Konformität_ kann nur mit einem irgendwie gearteten Maßstab bestehen. Winkel sind aber kein Maßstab. Eine Abbildung kann daher nicht _winkelkonform_ sein. Daher gebe ich hier -1

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach: Ich glaube, dieser Maßstab hat einen Namen – Jonathan Scholbach. War mein erster Gedanke. Mein zweiter: Wenn zwei in einer Frage konform gehen, sind sie sich in einem Punkt einig, wieso braucht es da einen Maßstab?

Comment: Mag sein, dass es hier subjektive Anteile gibt. Die von dir selbst zitierte Duden-Definition stützt jedoch meine Ansicht: eine _winkelkonforme Abbildung_ würde demnach bedeuten, dass die Abbildung mit den Winkeln übereinstimmt. Das ist aber hier nicht gemeint, sondern es geht darum, dass die Winkel in der Abbildung mit den tatsächlichen Winkeln übereinstimmen. Zum Gegenbeispiel würde ich sagen: Man kann in einer Frage nur _miteinander konform_ gehen, das mag zu _sie gehen konform_ verkürzt worden sein, das ändert aber nichts an meinem Argument, dass die Semantik von _winkelkonform_ schief ist.

Answer (score 1):

Ich halte das Wort "winkeltreu" für einen Fachausdruck, der in der Mathematik bzw. der Kartographie verwendet wird. Hier einige Wikipedia-Referenzen:

https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winkelverzerrung

https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Konforme_Abbildung

Die Frage steht zwar im Zusammenhang mit Geometrieaufgaben für Schüler und Studenten, d.h. hat einen mathematischen Kontext, ich rate aber von der Verwendung des Wortes "winkeltreu" ab - eben weil es zu einer Fachsprache gehört, die den meisten Adressaten fremd ist. Ich schlage vor, den Hinweis in anderer Form zu geben, etwa

"Achtung: Die Zeichnung gibt die Winkel nicht korrekt wieder."